# Regexp, replace certain combinations

Tags: javascript, regex

Got this string: `"'ab',('AA', 'BB'), r('rr')"`

I want the output to be `"'ab',['AA', 'BB'], r('rr')"`

Tried this

```
var replace = function(str){
    return str.replace(/\)/g, ']')
  .replace(/\(/g, '[')
}
```

It replaces all paranthes but how do I combine the regexp so it only replaces `,(` with `[`?

https://jsfiddle.net/tyapco67/

Comment: What is known about the content inside parenthesis? Is it always a comma-separate list of words?

Comment: so ,( should be replaced with ,[ and ), with ], right?

Comment: @PerStröm Try  to replace `'\,\('` with `,[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the comma before parenthesis:

```
return str.replace(/(,\s*)\((.*?)\)/g, '$1[$2]');
```

Answer (score 0):

without RegEx

```
"'ab',('AA', 'BB'), r('rr')".split(",(").join(",[").split("),").join("],")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `[^]*` inverse selector personally. Thus it doesn't require the comma.

```
var replace = function(str){
    return str.replace(/\(([^)]*)\)/g, "[$1]");
}
```

---

The currently accepted answer would produce `'ab',['AA', 'BB'], r('rr')`.